# Objects are not valid as a React child . If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

My schema for Teachers Model is this one:

```
tchStudents: [{
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  ref: "Student"
}]
```

Next is to populate using `mongoose-paginate`

```
const options = {
  select:  'tchID tchFirstName tchLastName tchStudents',
  sort:     { date: -1 },
  populate: 'tchStudents',
};

try {

  const tchID = await Teacher.paginate(req.query.tchID ? {tchID: req.query.tchID} : 
  {}, {limit, page, skip, options})
                       

  return res.status(200).json({
     success: true,
     data: tchID
  })

} catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```

The problem is how can render on my `react.js` even it is (declare `Schema.ObjectID` and render & populate on the browser) ?

```
<td>{enNum}</td>
<td>{enSclYear}</td>
<td>{enGrade}</td>
<td>{enSection}</td>
<td><Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{enDate}</Moment></td>
<td>{enStudent}</td> // It is a schema.ObjectId and populate on it 
(I want to render on it)
<td>
<Link 
   to={`/showEnroll/${enroll._id}`}
>
<Button
   tooltip="Edit Student"
   tooltipOptions={{
      position: 'left'
   }}
   className="btn blue darken-4"
>
<i className="material-icons center">create</i>
</Button>
</Link>
</td>
```

Thank you very much....

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your JSX code, there is no parent element. All children are at same level, probably that might be the reason, you are getting this error. You can use React.Fragments for this.

```
<React.Fragment>
    <td>Test</td>
    <Link to='/'>
        <Button>Test</Button>
    </Link>
</React.Fragment>
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Thank you Im resolving this one